# Fixing sharp edges between GeoTIFF tiles?

Tags: qgis, dem, geotiff-tiff

I've downloaded a couple SRTM DEMS from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org and when I load some of them into QGIS, there is a noticeable edge between 2 of the tiles (see image).

[image]

Why does it happen? These are both from the same datasource, why don't they match up? Is there a good way to correct for this in QGIS?

Comment: Ahah, I think I may have figured it out. I changed the Min and Max on the color gradient of all the tiles to match and it looks much better.

Comment: Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Comment: I don't think I can add it as an answer now that it's been marked as a duplicate.